# How can I know all possible ways that the edges are connected if I know the toposort in a graph?

Tags: algorithm, graph

How can I know all possible ways that the edges are connected if I know the topological sort?

Here is the original problem:

> Now little C has topologically sorted a simple (no heavy edges) directed acyclic graph, but accidentally lost the original. Except for topological sequences, little C only remembers that the original graph had the number of edges k, and that there is one vertex u in the graph that can reach all the other vertices. He wants to know how many simple directed acyclic graphs there are that satisfy the above requirements. Since the answer may be large, you only need to output the remainder of the answer module m.

I have just learned the topological sort. I wonder how I can use it in an upside down way? I know the final toposorted way as (1 2 3 4) and there is one vertex that connects all other vertexes, and there are 4 edges in all, but I need the number of all possible ways that edges are linked.

I think this problem has something to deal with permutation number，and the specific u has to be the first in the toposorted list.
NOTICE the max of m can be up to 200'000,so definitely you can not brute force this problem!!!

Answer (score 2):

Let the topological order be u = 1, 2, …, n. Since 1 can reach all other
vertices, the topological order begins with 1. Each node v > 1, being
reachable from u, must have arcs from one or more nodes < v. These
choices are linked only by the constraint on the number of arcs.

We end up computing `Count[v][m]` (modulo whatever the modulus is) as
the number of reconstructions on 1, 2, …, v with exactly m arcs. The
answer is `Count[n][k]`.

```
Count[1][0] = 1 if m == 0 else 0
for v > 1, Count[v][m] = sum for j = 1 to min(m, v-1) of (v-1 choose j)*Count[v-1][m-j]
```

Comment: m is too large to use brute forcing

Comment: @Rosamound this is not a brute force method.